# Lasagne/nolearn autoencoder - how to get hidden layer output?

Tags: python, neural-network, lasagne, autoencoder, nolearn

I've trained an autoencoder using lasagne/nolearn. Suppose the network layers are [500, 100, 100, 500]. I've trained the neural net like so:

```
net.fit(X, X)
```

I want to do something like the following:

```
net.predict(X, layer=2)
```

so I'll get the suppressed representation of my data. So, if my initial data have a shape [10000, 500], the resulting data will be [10000, 100].

I searched but could not find how to do that. 
Is it possible with lasagne/nolearn?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the answer is here in the documentation:
http://lasagne.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/layers.html#propagating-data-through-layers

Here are the relevant parts:

> To compute the output of a network, you should instead call
>   `lasagne.layers.get_output()` on it. This will traverse the network
>   graph.
>
> You can call this function with the layer you want to compute the
>   output expression for:
>
> ```
> >>> y = lasagne.layers.get_output(l_out)
> ```
>
> In that case, a Theano expression will be returned that represents the
>   output in function of the input variables associated with the
>   `lasagne.layers.InputLayer` instance (or instances) in the network
>
> ...
>
> You can also specify a Theano expression to use as input as a second argument to `lasagne.layers.get_output()`:
>
> ```
> >>> x = T.matrix('x')
> >>> y = lasagne.layers.get_output(l_out, x)
> >>> f = theano.function([x], y)
> ```

Assuming `net` is of type `nolearn.lasagne.NeuralNet` it looks like you can get access to the the underlying layer objects with `net.get_all_layers()`. I don't see it in the documentation but it's [here](https://github.com/dnouri/nolearn/blob/master/nolearn/lasagne/base.py) on line 592.

Comment: Hi ovolve. I've trained the network using nolearn on top of lasagne. I don't think I'm able to use the above code. The 'net' object is not used in the code. Do I miss something?

Comment: @Stergios Sorry, didn't realize nolearn hides the layers. I've updated the answer. Note I haven't tested this code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `net.predict(X, layer=2)`, try `net.get_output(net.layers_[1], X)`, or `net.get_output('name_of_layer_2' , X)` if you've named your layer.